# After fixing ext4 superblocks windows 10 won't run

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I recently used a program that will load my ubuntu files on windows. This created a drive and worked all well and good. However, when booting ubuntu it would take me to a terminal. From the errors it looked like a superblock issue. Using fsck the terminal asked if I would like to fix the issues. I said yes to all of them.

That then fixed my ubuntu boot which I could run. However now I get the blue screen error when trying to run windows - it stays with the logo and loading circle for a while before showing the blue screen. Any thoughts on what might be occurring and how to fix it?

I will come back to edit this post w/ more info about the error, however if possible to help without extra info that is great.

Comment: This is a bit vague. One assumes "a program" had a name? Is there a link to instructions that you followed? Is 'a terminal' really an ordinary terminal and not the recovery console or a tty console? What is "the blue screen error when trying to run windows" (never heard of it)? Did you really use fsck on your Windows partition?

Comment: Windows drivers that allow you to read/write to Linux (Ubuntu) file systems tend to corrupt those file systems. That's why you had to fsck your Ubuntu partition. You'll need to fix your BSOD using the Windows install/repair disc.

Comment: ps: once you get Windows to boot properly, you'll want to uninstall that Windows driver that you installed to access Ubuntu partitions.